# How to export pdf or send e-mail that contains html including borders?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, pdf

I have a website that displays data with some html and the data that is displayed on the webpage has borders as it is contained in a container-fluid with bootstrap. My problem comes when I export the page as a pdf, or try to send the html as it is in an email. When I look at the pdf file that comes from the site, it has all of the contents of the different rows and columns, but there is no shape or borders for any of the cells that show up on the site.

Does this have something to do with the fact that the original way that the data is displayed on the website is using a bootstrap container rather than a table? The data is not currently set up as an html table as the fields of the data that I show on the website are set up in a specific way. Is there any way to keep this format in the export?

[Here's what my page roughly looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vfiD.png) Each of the cells holds data, but I want to be able to see the data as well as the borders of the cells when I export this as a pdf. As it is, I only see the contents of the cells but no borders or formatting.

Also, here is the function I'm using to export as a pdf:

```
function exportPDF() {
            var divToPrint=document.getElementById("content");
            newWin= window.open("");
            newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
            newWin.print();
            newWin.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Often the borders are CSS formatted. Meaning that if you have a separate piece of code that contains the CSS styling, outside of the "content" div this will have no effect in your export. Could you check if this is the case? Perhaps you can add the CSS styling directly into the HTML code like this example:

```
<h1 style="color:blue;">A Blue Heading</h1>
```

Best regards